# How do I check if an array index is out of range SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to be able to check when my array index goes out of range. The array elements are all strings, so I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
if questions[3] != nil {
}
```

Can someone just show me how to check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before indexing into the array, you need to check:

1. The intended index is not below 0
2. array's `count` is above the intended index

---

```
let intendedIndex: Int = 3

if (intendedIndex >= 0 && questions.count > intendedIndex) {
    // This line will not throw index out of range:
    let question3 = questions[intendedIndex]
}
```

Comment: not really Swift specific but obviously a working solution. Was hoping a bit for a Swift specific method or something but guess the is no such thing.

Comment: So not to go far away by other links:

if (questions.indices.contains(intendedIndex)) {
   ...
}